# Category collection with filter Magento2

Tags: magento2, collection, category-attribute

I have created custom Drop down attribute for category with attribute_code is "**is_homecategory**"

Used below methods to create it.

Setup/InstallData.php

```
  public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'is_homecategory',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Is Home Category',
                'input' => 'select',
                'sort_order' => 333,
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '0',
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
```

and view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_from.xml

```
<fieldset name="general">
        <field name="is_homecategory">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Is Home Category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
```

That is created with Yes/No drop down in admin.

I am getting collection like below in by block file.

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
protected $collectionFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category $collectionFactory,
    array $data = []) {

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function getCategoryData(){

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection');
    $category->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setPageSize(1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_homecategory',['eq'=>1]
    ->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc')
    );
    return $category;
    /* $categories =   $this->collectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_homecategory',1)->load();
    return categories; */
  }
```

}

Which is not returning any results to me.

All i am looking is I need to get only one category recently set as is_homecategory as 'Yes'.

Can i filter category collection in that way?
Please anyone check it and help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to complete addAttributeToFilter() bracket. Use this below code :

```
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection');
    $category->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setPageSize(1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_homecategory',['eq'=>1])
    ->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc');
```

Use default argument in config for default set value

```
<item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
```

Comment: hi, @Rohan, Thanks it worked for me, but default value is Showing 'Yes' for me. shall we make default as 'No'?

Comment: Whenever i create create new category always it is selected with 'Yes' I need to make it "No'. How that can be done please?

Comment: I will update my answer soon.

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: 1 is yes is it? I need to set as No

Comment: You can check option value by inspect elements. Generally, 0 is for set No

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85686/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 0):

> **Please try the code below to retrieve all categories with filtered custom attributes:**

```
protected $categoryCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    .......................................................................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
    .......................................................................................

) {
    .......................................................................................
    $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
    .......................................................................................
}    

public function getAllCategory()
{
    $categoryColl = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $categoryColl->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    $categoryColl->addAttributeToFilter('is_homecategory',['eq' => 1 ]);
    $categoryColl->setOrder('updated_at', 'desc');
    return $categoryColl;
}
```